# How to use Umalqura calendar in java 8 with java.util.Date

Tags: java-8, umalquracalendar

we hear those days that java8 will includes  **Umalqura calendar** APi which manages Hijri Date .

Where to find a sample that convert Date To Hijri ?

Indeed , i find this code :

```
HijrahDate hdate = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(LocalDate.of(2014, Month.JANUARY, 9));
```

However , i cannot set one INPUT (java.util.Date )instead of 3 INPUTS (YEAR,MONTH ,DATE)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert from a `LocalDate` - how you get that is up to you. For example:

```
// Avoid using java.util.Date unless you really have to.
// Stick to java.time.* if possible
Date date = ...; 
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());

// Pick the time zone you actually want here...
LocalDate localDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDate();  

HijrahDate hdate = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(instant);
```

Comment: ≫ java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: EpochDay
 at java.time.Instant.getLong(Instant.java:603)
 at java.time.chrono.HijrahChronology.date(HijrahChronology.java:523)
 at java.time.chrono.HijrahChronology.date(HijrahChronology.java:217)

Comment: @عبدالنورالتومي: Interesting - try converting to a `LocalDate` first. I'll do that too :)